# Why does matching the RegEx only work when setting a breakpoint?

Tags: regex, eclipse, debugging, junit, breakpoints

The following JUnit test will only run correctly for me when I set a breakpoint on the matcher line. When running it normally or debugging it without a breakpoint it will fail.

```
public class ParserTest {
@Test
public void test() {
    final String s = new Parser().parse("Hello(WORLD)");
}

public static class Parser {
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("([a-zA-Z\\s]*)\\(([A-Z]{5,5})\\)");

    public String parse(final String raw) {
        // put a breakpoint on the matcher in eclipse,
        // debug as junit test, then step over
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(raw);
        return matcher.group(2) + ":" + matcher.group(1);
    }
}
}
```

The following exception is thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:461)
at lab.ParserTest$Parser.parse(ParserTest.java:22)
at lab.ParserTest.test(ParserTest.java:11)
```

I create a RegEx Planet Cookbook [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/agtyZWdleHBsYW5ldHINCxIGUmVjaXBlGPIuDA/index.html) and it works fine.

Comment: So as @sblundy and @bouzuya pointed out I forgot to call `matches()` on the `Matcher` object. The question still stands though why the debugger will evaluate the matcher object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`matcher.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) before `matcher.group()`. Sometimes examining code in a debugger cause the state of an object to change because it forces things to evaluate. I suspect that's happening here.

Comment: So the debugger automatically calls `matcher.matches()`? That doesn't really help in the debugging process.

Comment: @oschrenk it's usually the toString() that causes trouble. Most IDE java debuggers call it to display the local variables. This has bit me a few times when debugging hibernate lazy loading problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public String parse(final String raw) {
        // put a breakpoint on the matcher in eclipse,
        // debug as junit test, then step over
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(raw);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return matcher.group(2) + ":" + matcher.group(1);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```